# Evaluate the probability that at least one of the events A, B, or C occurs

Tags: probability

Suppose that A, B, and C are events such that P(A) = P(B) = P(C) = 1/4,
P(A ∩ B) = P(C ∩ B) = 0, and P(A ∩ C) = l/8· Evaluate the probability that at
least one of the events A, B, or C occurs

I can't wrap my head around the logic needed in order to get the answer (5/8)

The only think I can (incorrectly) logically conclude is P(A) OR P(B) OR P(C) = (1/4) + (1/4) + (1/4) = 3/4

Comment: What do you mean by P(A n C)?

Comment: What is $P(A n B)$?  The $n$ looks like you might be thinking intersection, but $P(A n C)=1$ is impossible.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  As others have pointed out, you can't have $P(A\cap C)=1$ as $P(A\cap C)≤P(A)=\frac 14$.  If you meant something else, please edit accordingly.

Comment: The end result is that you should use the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) $P(A\cup B\cup C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)\color{red}{-P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap C)-P(B\cap C)+P(A\cap B\cap C)}$.  Do not forget the part in red.  It is *not* true that "or" simply means add, that only happens when the terms are mutually exclusive which they don't appear to be (*once you fix what you've written*)

Comment: As an aside, given $P(A\cup B\cup C)=\frac{5}{8}$, $P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=\frac{1}{4}$ and $P(A\cap B)=P(B\cap C)=0$, that will imply $P(A\cap B\cap C)\leq P(A\cap B)=0$ implying $P(A\cap B\cap C)=0$, further implying from inclusion-exclusion above that the missing number from your post should be $P(A\cap C)=\frac{1}{8}$.  Please be careful to correctly include all necessary information for the problem and avoid typos or missing details.

Comment: Apologies, copy and paste turned an intersection into an n and I didn't spot it.

Comment: I see you attempted to edit using better symbols., if you were to edit further using [MathJax and $\LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) it would look even better and more uniform with the rest of the site, also helping the automated search engine in finding related questions and helping future users in finding your questions.  Also you still haven't corrected $P(A\cap C)=\color{red}{\ell}$ into a proper value.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have edited it again.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing $A,B,C$ are events where $P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=\frac{1}{4}$, $P(A\cap B)=P(B\cap C)=0$ and $P(A\cap C)=\frac{1}{8}$, the probability that at least one of the events occurs is:

By [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle):

$$P(A\cup B\cup C)=\underbrace{P(A)}_{=\frac{1}{4}}+\underbrace{P(B)}_{=\frac{1}{4}}+\underbrace{P(C)}_{=\frac{1}{4}}\color{red}{-}\underbrace{\color{red}{P(A\cap B)}}_{=0}\color{red}{-}\underbrace{\color{red}{P(A\cap C)}}_{=\frac{1}{8}}\color{red}{-}\underbrace{\color{red}{P(B\cap C)}}_{=0}\color{red}{+ P(A\cap B\cap C)}$$

In your "attempt" you completely left out everything which I colored red above.

Now, recognize that $P(A\cap B\cap C)\leq \min\{P(A\cap B),P(A\cap C),P(B\cap C)\}=\min\{0,0,\frac{1}{8}\}=0$ and the only probability less than or equal to zero possible is zero itself, implying $P(A\cap B\cap C)=0$

We get then $P(A\cup B\cup C)=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}-0-\frac{1}{8}-0+0=\frac{5}{8}$

---

I will reiterate that $P(A~\text{or}~B)=P(A\cup B)$ is **not** equal to $P(A)+P(B)$ under normal circumstances.  Instead you have $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$.  You have $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$ *only when the intersection of the events is an "almost impossible" or an impossible event (such as is the case when $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive)*.

> Almost impossible events are those events with probability equal to zero but aren't necessarily empty, and correspond with null sets in measure space theory.  For example, picking a real number uniformly at random on the range $[0,1]$, the probability the number is in the range $[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}]$ is $\frac{1}{4}$, but the probability that the number selected is exactly equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ is equal to zero.  That is not to say that you could never select $\frac{1}{2}$, it is saying that it happens so infrequently that no strictly positive probability could accurately describe it, leaving the only feasible choice for a value to be zero.

Similarly, $P(A~\text{and}~B)=P(A\cap B)$ is **not** equal to $P(A)\cdot P(B)$ under normal circumstances.  Instead you have $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B\mid A)$.  One has $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$ *only when the events are independent*.

Answer (score 0):

P(atleast one of A,B,C occur) $= P(A\cup B\cup C) 
= P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A\cap B)-P(B\cap C)-P(A\cap C)+P(A\cap B\cap C) 
= \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}-0-0-\frac{1}{8}+0
 = \frac{5}{8}$